# SSEemitter vs Flux in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, flux, server-sent-events

I am having confusion between the SSEemitter and flux in spring Boot for sending one way asynchronous message to the client.

Want to know the use cases for both the terms with respect to Spring boot

Answer (score 0):

One is using reactive/Flux and another is not. [Here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-sse-streams) SSEemitter based implementation. You don't need reactive background. Reactive can take some time to understand if you haven't done it earlier.